# href attribute in stylesheet link does not work in node

Tags: html, node.js, express

I tried running my website 2 methods.
1) By using node
2) Without using node(just index.html on my computer) 
However, the outcomes are different in terms of linking stylesheet. Without node, the stylesheet in style tag could be linked as usual. However, when using node as a server, the stylesheet cannot be linked.

Here is the structure of my code.

```
/app
  /server.js
  /views
    /statics
        /index.html
    /partials
  /public
    /javascript
    /css
        /main.css
    /images
```

here is the index.html head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../public/css/main.css">
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
// no need to use app.use(app.router) because of that update
// function signature express.static(root, [options])

app.use(express.static('public'));

// mount root to views/statics
app.use('/', express.static('views/statics'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you did not provide the path under which your assets should be available under with

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

According to [the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) in such case subfolders from the public folder will get served from root path.

In general you should avoid serving assets by relative path. In your case `href="/css/main.css"` should work. Node acts as a server and you define the paths under which given resources are available in `server.js`. You can't access them under the directory structure path of your filesystem

Comment: Thank you very much. You mentioned about avoiding using relative path, what is the absolute path in this case then? By using __dirname?

Comment: using __dirname helps a bit when you have to restructure your project but what I ment is using href="../../some/path. It can work, but if you use relative paths like that you'll have hard time refactoring your site structure down the road when the project gets bigger.

Comment: So what is the absolute path in this case then? Usually an absolute path is something like http://www.example.com no?

Answer (score 2):

Make **Public** directory accessible by stating it as assets directory. In your server, add the code below:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname+'/views/public'));
```

Then static files can be accessed as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/assets/css/main.css">
```